# Java Code Signing Without Private/Public Keys

Tags: java, csr

How do I go about signing jar files if the private/public keys and CSR were generated on somebody else's computer? I have the certificate but what I am trying to understand is can the certificate only be used to sign jar files on the computer that the CSR was generated on or do I need to get that person to send me the private/public keys?

Answer (score 0):

PKI Signatures are created by yourself with your private key and checked by others with your public key .

Trust is established when (a) the signature is valid and matches the certificate that signed it and (b) the entity checking the signature either trusts your certificate directly or trusts the entity that signed it, the CA.

The CSR is of no interest in this process and other peoples certificates are not used.

Hope that clears it up.